# How can I match screws with both fractional and metric descriptions?

Tags: screws

A Pottery Barn bed (gifted me is) missing the hardware needed to assemble it (got lost by movers). The screws listed in the assembly instruction packet seem to be  hybrid metric/imperial screws.  Pottery Barn has been no use.

Suggestions on how to find screws that will match these?

[image]

Comment: All the hardware? You don't have anything you could take to a hardware store to find a compatible bolt?

Comment: I'm pretty sure 1/4" is just the size of bit used to drive those screws.  That doesn't matter for finding a replacement (assuming you have the correct bit to drive whatever replacement you find).

Comment: Is 13mm with shank diameter or the head diameter?

Comment: I suspect—but obviously have no way to verify—that the 1/4" is the threads, the 50 and 28 are the length, and the 13mm is the head diameter.  Go to the hardware store and find 1/4" machine screws that look similar.  You'll probably find them in the drawers rather than on a rack.  Drive type doesn't even really need to be a hex.

Comment: I'd guess the same as @Huesmann, because diameter x length is a normal way to describe screws amd there's nothing else that looks like a diameter. 13mm could be the head diameter (1/2"), 50mm is near enough 2" long, and 28mm  1 1/8".

Answer (score 3):

Go to a traditional hardware store. Might be an Ace Hardware or may be totally independent. If you truly don't have any place like that, then you *may* do OK at a Home Depot or Lowes or similar, but the little places tend to have a much larger selection of (literally) nuts and bolts. Bring the pictures/dimensions. They will either help you find it in the hundreds of drawers of hardware or they will disappear for a couple of minutes and come back with the parts in hand.

Note that in most cases the head type does *not* matter with the exception that if the head is designed to be flush then it may *have* to be flush for another part to fit over it. But hex (allen), phillips, Torx, etc. generally doesn't matter. Length, thickness (diameter), type of threads matter.

Comment: If you and the sales guy at the small store really aren't sure, but 1 each of several sizes, put them each in carefully labeled bags, then take them home and figure out which one(s) fit where. Return the ones that don't fit, buy additional ones of those that do fit.

Comment: You wouldn't be the first one to walk into a hardware store with a large plank of wood just to match a threaded nut built into it. I promise.

Comment: @jay613 That's a different meaning of "walk the plank"

Answer (score 1):

If the (better) idea of taking the matching parts to a hardware store doesn't work for you, you can buy screw gauges and subsequently screws online quite easily.

I don't think any of the dimensions in the manual is the thread pitch. They only give you enough to distinguish the included screws from each other.  You don't have enough info in the manual to replace them.

Following is just a random example available in USA, not a recommendation:

[image]